# Can I rename my CD or DVD drive?

Tags: windows, burning, optical-drive, compact-disc

I have 7 CD drives. Currently I'm writing the CDs using NTI Media Maker.

The problem is that all drives have weird name like HL DVD-RW S224. It is very hard to find which drive is which.

Is there any way to rename a drive to Drive 1 or Drive 2 so I can clearly see which drive failed to write a CD in NTI Media Maker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking up the name of the software, it seems you're on Windows XP or Vista.

You can change the drive labels in the registry, but you will have to make some keys are they are not there by default.

- Open regedit from the run box (XP) or Start menu search (Vista)
- Expand the treeview in the left pane to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`
- Right click the **Explorer** key and select **New -> Key** and call this new key **DriveIcons**
- Right click this DriveIcons key, and create new keys underneath it **for each drive** you want to modify, then inside those keys, create one more key called **DefaultLabel**, once again this also must be done for each drive

For example, if I wanted to modify the `D:` drive, the key hierarchy should look like this:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\DriveIcons\D\DefaultLabel
```

Remember, every single drive must have:

- It's own drive letter underneath the **DriveIcons** key.
- and it's own **DefaultLabel** key under the drive letter key, for a total of 2 keys per drive.

now inside the DefaultLabel key for each drive, there should be a default string value created. Modify it to whatever label you desire:

[image]

Your drives should now have different names:

[image]

Comment: Does this apply to Windows 7?

Comment: Unfortunatly, while this method partiall works in Windows 10 as well, results are bit different - it appends your custom name at the END of the already existing drive name. So, for example - i had "DVD RW Drive (G:)", and after applying method described above, I got "DVD RW Drive (G:) MyLabel"